# Creating 4k HDR video from 720p footage

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, applications, research

So, my company recently bought a big 4k HDR TV for our reception, where we keep showing some videos that were originally shot/created at 720p resolution. Before this, we had a relatively small HD TV, so not a problem. Because the old videos now look dated, my boss wanted to upscale them and enhance their coloring to avoid shooting or procuring new animated videos.

This sounded like a fun project, but I know little about AI, and less so about video encoding/decoding. I've started researching and found some references, such as [Video Super-Resolution via Bidirectional
Recurrent Convolutional Networks](http://ir.ia.ac.cn/bitstream/173211/14820/1/TPAMI_final.pdf), so while it seems like I have homework to do, it's clearly "been done before". Would be great to find some code that works on standard formatted videos though.

What I'm struggling to find, but would need some good basis to answer in the negative, is: **What about HDR?** I'm not finding the research terms nor any mention on result for improving dynamic range on videos. Is there any research done on that? Though actual HDR is a format, most of the shots and pictures used for our videos were taken on cameras with small color gamut and latitude, thus everything looks "washed" and the new TV really makes this obvious by comparing against demo videos.

**PS:**
Unlike much of the literature I'm finding, I'm not aiming at real-time super resolution, it would be great if it took less than one night to process for a 10 minute video though.